# ubuntu support intermittent connectivity ssh session

Tags: server, ssh, internet, 16.10, disconnect

Recently I moved and with the new wifi router (tp-link) I noticed I get kicked out from ssh sessions, the shell gets stuck and I cant type anything and I have to close it.

I am not sure how to test it, pinging to google it looks like:

```
icmp_seq=157 ttl=56 time=31.6 ms
icmp_seq=158 ttl=56 time=31.4 ms
icmp_seq=159 ttl=56 time=202 ms
icmp_seq=160 ttl=56 time=31.2 ms
icmp_seq=161 ttl=56 time=31.7 ms
```

...

```
icmp_seq=92 ttl=56 time=31.2 ms
icmp_seq=93 ttl=56 time=144 ms
icmp_seq=94 ttl=56 time=144 ms
icmp_seq=95 ttl=56 time=31.1 ms
```

and I think thats what kicks me out.

Any way to avoid this? I could try using mosh https://mosh.org/ but its possible to configure the ssh service to support intermittent connectivity?

Comment: Check the [ClientAliveInterval](http://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ClientAliveInterval) ssh option.

Comment: Regarding "the shell gets stuck and I cant type anything and I have to close it" — try <kbd>enter</kbd>+`~`+`.` as it's an escape sequence to disconnect (see `man ssh`)

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm new, I can't leave a comment, so I'll leave it here. You could try iperf to check your connection speed and how moving devices around changes it. There was a recent video that showed how you hold a cell phone changes your connectinon speeds.

With moving and new router you have a lot of other variables also to consider.

I have a laptop doing the same thing. ssh will hang for 1 to 3 minutes, but resumes connection. Moving around doesn't change anything. In this case, it's just getting old. If not for it's 17 insch screen I would be using my other.